# Ansible aws_eks_cluster module invalid parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-eks

I am using the older `aws_eks_cluster` module to create an EKS cluster, i am aware there is a newer one which is `eks_cluster`.
I am passing temporary aws credentials i got from `sts_assume_role` to the module which are:

```
aws_access_key
aws_secret_key
security_token
```

They have been working fine authenticating with other modules.
However with `aws_eks_cluster`  module, I am getting an invalid length parameter for the security_token.

The security token length i am getting from `sts_assume_role` is 356 chars.
however the error specifies a length between 33 and 126 chars.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding credentials, that module (and all modules, AFAIK) honor [`aws_config:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/community/aws/aws_eks_cluster_module.html#parameter-aws_config); have you tried that? You can not only use longer lines, you can also use its support for [`role_arn =`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#assume-role-provider) and save yourself the manual step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug related to the old version of the module. The error is unrelated.